# Cannot access SD card on Yun

Tags: arduino-yun, sd-card

I have a brand new 8GB micro SD card freshly formatted as FAT in my Yun.

When I run `df -h`, I don't see the card's capacity included.
When I enter `cd /mnt/sda1`, it says `can't cd to /mnt/sda1`.

When I SSH into the Yun with `ssh root@arduino.local` and run `dmesg`, I see confirmation that the SD card is recognized:

```
[   11.510000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 15431680 512-byte logical blocks: (7.90 GB/7.35 GiB)
[   11.510000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[   11.510000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[   11.510000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page present
[   11.510000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   11.520000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page present
[   11.520000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   11.530000]  sda: sda1
[   11.530000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page present
[   11.530000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   11.540000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

How can I access my SD card and include it in the Yun's recognized storage space?

Comment: I take it you've mounted the SD card, with `mkdir -p /mnt/sda1` and then `mount  /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1` ...?

Comment: I ended up resetting my Yun and following the Arduino tutorial to expand disk space. But, thank you for that comment - as funny as it sounds, I didn't know to do that!